# Display a div when an input div is focused

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, focus

I want to display a div when an input field is focused(active?)
In the following code, I want to display `.text` when `.input` is focused.
I'm trying this:

***HTML :***

```
<div class="box">
    <input class="input" type="text" value="" />
    <div class="text">text</div>
</div>
```

***CSS :***

```
.text { display: none; }   
.input:focus .text { display: block; }
```

***Example :***

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AxM35/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [sibling CSS selector](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/):

```
.input:focus + .text{
    display: block;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AxM35/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [**general sibling selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` :

```
.input:focus ~ .text { display: block; }
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AxM35/2/)